# How can I execute shell command line in MEAN stack?

Tags: php, node.js, mean-stack

Hello I'm a very newbie in MEAN stack.

Previously I used php for web development, and I usually used "shell_exec" to browse server json files and read them.

How can I execute shell command line in MEAN stack?

What is "shell_exec" in MEAN stack?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to browse json - it's much simplier:

```
const data = require('./some-file.json');
```

In case if you still need exec, here it is:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('cat *.js bad_file | wc -l', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me .. var exec = require("child_process").exec;